runs\train\exp10 is not a directory
I am trying to train a YoloV5 model with my custom data on my own computer, but I keep getting this error:
train: weights=yolov5s.pt, cfg=models/yolov5s.yaml, data=data.yaml, hyp=data\hyps\hyp.scratch-low.yaml, epochs=300, batch_size=32, imgsz=640, rect=False, resume=False, nosave=False, noval=False, noautoanchor=False, noplots=False, evolve=None, evolve_population=data\hyps, resume_evolve=None, bucket=, cache=None, image_weights=False, device=, multi_scale=False, single_cls=False, optimizer=SGD, sync_bn=False, workers=8, project=runs\train, name=exp, exist_ok=False, quad=False, cos_lr=False, label_smoothing=0.0, patience=100, freeze=[0], save_period=-1, seed=0, local_rank=-1, entity=None, upload_dataset=False, bbox_interval=-1, artifact_alias=latest, ndjson_console=False, ndjson_file=False
    github: skipping check (not a git repository), for updates see https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5
    YOLOv5  2024-7-15 Python-3.12.2 torch-2.3.1+cpu CPU
    hyperparameters: lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=0.05, cls=0.5, cls_pw=1.0, obj=1.0, obj_pw=1.0, iou_t=0.2, anchor_t=4.0, fl_gamma=0.0, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0
    TensorBoard: Start with 'tensorboard --logdir runs\train', view at http://localhost:6006/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\yolov5_work2024\yolov5-master\train.py", line 986, in <module>
        main(opt)
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\yolov5_work2024\yolov5-master\train.py", line 688, in main
        train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\yolov5_work2024\yolov5-master\train.py", line 180, in train
        loggers = Loggers(
                  ^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\yolov5_work2024\yolov5-master\utils\loggers\__init__.py", line 121, in __init__
        self.tb = SummaryWriter(str(s))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 249, in __init__
        self._get_file_writer()
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 281, in _get_file_writer
        self.file_writer = FileWriter(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\tensorboard\writer.py", line 75, in __init__
        self.event_writer = EventFileWriter(**
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\writer\event_file_writer.py", line 72, in __init__
        tf.io.gfile.makedirs(logdir)
      File "C:\Users\Usuário\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 513, in recursive_create_dir_v2
        _pywrap_file_io.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: runs\train\exp10 is not a directory

I have tried training my model from a pre-trained one (as the yolov5 docs recommend), like this:
python train.py --img 640 --batch 32 --epochs 300 --data data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt
or from scratch, like this:
python train.py --img 640 --batch 32 --epochs 300 --data data.yaml --cfg models/yolov5s.yaml
I have also seen other issues, like issue #12008 on GitHub and this issue from Stack Overflow tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: runs\train\exp3 is not a directory, but havent found any solution

Have your script in a folder in google drive. Connect your Colab workspace with your Google Drive. You don't even have to remember the code for it when you press button it automatically gets added at the top. Now run all of your commands. Now your Yolov5 folder should be saved in the folder you created and your runs are saved there as well, make sure that you are in the selected folder by running path and cd to navigate
